# gitattributes -merge for one specific directory (existing repo)

Tags: git, gitattributes

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I've searched but not found anything that seems to work.

I have a git repo that is up and running with history, different branches etc.

The repo doesn't have a pre-existing `.gitattribute` file, so I've added one.

My `.gitattribute` is located in the root folder and contains the following:

```
#I've tried the following:
#./src/views/component-testing -merge
#./src/views/component-testing/*.* -merge

#Current content:
./src/views/component-testing/* -merge
```

I'm then trying to merge another branch (with a conflicting file in component-testing) into my current one. This is the result:

```
> git merge conflicting-branch
Auto-merging src/views/component-testing/component-testing.tsx
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/views/component-testing/component-testing.tsx
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1):

There's three problems here:

1. `-merge` looks like an *attribute* for the `.gitattributes` file, it does not belong in the `.gitignore`.
2. `-merge` doesn't mean "don't merge these files", it means that these files are not automergable.  In other words, their contents do not make any sense to be attempted to be three-way merged, usually because they are completely rewritten every time and have no regions in common.  (Perhaps because they're binary.)
3. Files can't be ignored once they're checked in to the repository.  If you have a merge conflict, because you've changed the file in two different branches, then you need to resolve that somehow.  You could always take the *theirs* side of the merge, but you must act.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! the `.gitignore` was a typo from my point. I mean't `.gitattributes` (see my edit).
So how would I specify that I allways want _their_ side of the merge for this specific file?